# How to trace and debug IPC (interprocess communication)

Tags: macos, dtrace

I have a problem with my distnoted process that I'm trying to debug.  In order to investigate it, I'd like to trace the interprocess communication that's happening on my OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks) system.  I know about dtruss, and I can see things like this:

```
% dtruss -p 263

SYSCALL(args)        = return
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x3, 0x7FFF76D54130, 0x1)       = 1 0
kevent64(0x3, 0x7FFF76D54130, 0x1)       = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
kevent64(0x3, 0x7FFF76D54130, 0x1)       = 1 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x10E810000, 0x7FFF783E8258, 0x1010101)        = 5185362 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x110219000, 0x7FFF783E8258, 0x1010101)        = 5185368 0
workq_kernreturn(0x20, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
```

I have heard that dtrace is available for me to use, but I don't know
any good recipes for IPC.

Comment: What kind of problem do you have with `distnoted`?

Comment: This is what's happening to me : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111197/runaway-distnoted-process

Comment: Have you tried 10.9.4 rolled out recently?

Comment: Actually it does seem to be fixed (after observing for a few weeks) by 10.9.4.  I updated my comment in the other thread.