# distnoted service memory leak

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, macos

I have problem on Mavericks 10.9.5. When my macbook air (mid 2012) awake, it freezes on 5-10 minutes.
Sometimes I keep up to show process list and I see that "distnoted" service eats all CPU time.

I looked at another issues by "distnoted" problem and all of them was related to Emacs version. But I don't use it. How can problem be fixed?

MacBook Air, OS X Mavericks (10.9.5)

Comment: Do you have the Console report for that time stamp when it freezes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [runaway distnoted process](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111197/runaway-distnoted-process)

Comment: I saw this ticket, but it points to update Emacs, but I don't use Emacs at all.

Comment: I have only those records in system console: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s336/sh/b1f4d606-620b-4b67-8300-277966627fb7/855e5ed3d8c726ac3cc5fdae1391d01f

Comment: When you click on details what do you you get? Also are you using Skype ? Distnoted= Distributed Notifications